# Spring batch summary after one group is finished

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to implement a batch job where we are processing data for multiple student departments. We are reading data from DB & writing it to a file and once a particular department execution is done we need to print the summary of students in that department. In the query we are fetching students records in the sorting order of department, once all the students are processed for a department i.e. department id changes we need to print a summary of previously processed department.

Sample records from query result looks like below

| studentId | deptid | firstName | lastName | DOB | feesPaid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | firstFN | firstLN | 02/02/2020 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | secondFN | secondLN | 02/02/2020 | 110 |
| 3 | 1 | thirdFN | thirdLN | 02/02/2020 | 105 |
| 4 | 2 | fourthFN | fourthLN | 02/02/2020 | 200 |
| 5 | 2 | fifthFN | fifthLN | 02/02/2020 | 190 |

My requirement is to first records for a department first and then summary,  then records for next department so on.
So final output file looks like

| studentId | deptid | firstName | lastName | DOB | feesPaid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | firstFN | firstLN | 02/02/2020 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | secondFN | secondLN | 02/02/2020 | 110 |
| 3 | 1 | thirdFN | thirdLN | 02/02/2020 | 105 |

| deptid | studentCount | FeesTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 315 |

| studentId | deptid | firstName | lastName | DOB | feesPaid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | fourthFN | fourthLN | 02/02/2020 | 200 |
| 5 | 2 | fifthFN | fifthLN | 02/02/2020 | 190 |

| deptid | studentCount | FeesTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 390 |

I tried to use SpringBatch Repository reader. I think it can be taken care by some listener but not exactly sure which listener and at how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The chunk-oriented processing model of Spring Batch is *not* suitable to your use case. Your SQL query can have a "group by" clause to group students by department, but the issue is that one group of items can span multiple chunks (depending on the chunk-size).

In my opinion, you need to first design a solution (without referring to Spring Batch) on how to solve this requirement. If you share your solution, I can try to help you implementing it with Spring Batch by editing this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Without Spring batch my one of the options was to basically iterate over all the records, process each of them and write to file; store previous dept id in some temporary variable, along with storing summary records. Once the dept id changes I would go and write dept summary in the file.

Comment: I think you need to do this in two steps: step 1 calculates distinct departments, and step 2 iterates over departments and appends records + summary into the output file. The list of distinct departments can be shared through the job execution context.